# Ajax/Coffescript form update without reloading page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, coffeescript

I have an order form on an item show page:

```
<%= form_for(Order.new, remote: true) do |f| %>
   <%= f.number_field :quantity_requested, value: 0, max: @item.quantity, min: 1, class: "item-quantity form-control"  %>
       <%= f.hidden_field :item_id, value: @item.id %>
<% end %>
```

I have to reload the page in order for the new quantity to update in the database.  I would like for it to update in the db without having to refresh the page.

This is what I have in my item coffeescript:

```
$ ->
  $('.item-quantity').click () ->
    $(this).closest('form').submit(); 
        $.ajax(url: item_url).done (html) ->
            $('.item-quantity').append html
```

And this is what I have in my order controller:

```
def create
    @order = Order.find_or_initialize_by(user_id: current_user.id, item_id: params[:order][:item_id])
    @order.update_attribute(:quantity_requested, params[:order][:quantity_requested])
    @order.save
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to :back }
      format.js { redirect_to :back }
    end 
  end
```

I suspect my error is in coffeescript.  I've tried adding return false and prevent default but that doesn't work.  Can anyone help?  Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean here? I suspect it means that the function continues to reload the page instead of reloading in place. If so, that's probably because you're calling `submit()` on your form. Default behavior when submitting a form is to reload the entire page. What you'll want to do is serialize the data from the form into your ajax call without calling `submit()`.

Comment: Yes, you are correct, sorry if I was unclear.  Thanks for the lead.